# Choosing differential receiver IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, comparator, differential, offset

I have a differential signal A which I would like to convert to LVTTL output X as follows:

X = 1 iff A+ > A- + 50 mV. That is to say, X is '1' only when A+ is more than 50 mV greater than A-.

Normally, A+ is never lower than A-. At minimum, it 20 mV or so higher than A-. The maximum difference between A+ and A- is about 250 mV. The common-mode voltage of A is about 2.5V. Given input A, the output X would switch from high to low no more frequently than every 5 us.

Looking online, I see lots of differential receiver ICs, but it seems my requirement (X = 1 iff A+ > A- + 50 mV) is a rare one.

I thought about subtracting A+ and A- using an op-amp, then comparing that to a 50mV signal with another op-amp or comparator, but I am afraid of introducing too much latency into my signal, as well as problems with frequency and slew rate through the op-amp. I would also need to first buffer A+ and A- since the current draw of the op-amp's feedback network in a differential amplifier configuration would be too high.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at LVDS buffers. Although I agree that 50mV is a rather problematic requirement.

Comment: You say you're worried about speed, but the only mention that comes close is 5 us which is _NOT_ speedy at all.  Could you refine your question and specify edge rates and perhaps add in a drawing of the signals?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to amplify your signals. A properly designed comparator circuit should be able to provide the performance that you require even including the addition of a small amount of hysteresis to prevent oscillation right at the threshold levels.

There are plenty of comparators to choose from that are high enough speed even with signal propagation speeds in the 10's of nanoseconds. The 2.5V common mode range should also not be a problem. Do note that many of the "low power" style of comparators are intentionally bandwidth and slew rate limited to keep power dissipation as low as possible. Do expect to find higher power consumption in components as the bandwidth and slew rates approach higher performance levels.

**UPDATE**

You may want to consider the use of the [MC3450 / MC3550](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/mc3450.pdf) parts from TI. Whilst these parts are fairly old they provide ball park of input sensitivity that you are after (these are working at +/-25 mV differential sensitivity). The parts are quad receivers.